# How to quote this on Ruby?

Tags: ruby, string

i have as string, with these value:

```
'`~!@#:;|$%^>?,)_+-={][&*(<]./"'
```

how to declare it on .rb without heredoc?

with heredoc:

```
bla = <<_
'`~!@#:;|$%^>?,)_+-={][&*(<]./"'
_
bla.chop!
```

Comment: Just like you typed it?

Comment: how to do it without heredoc? it's easy when without single quote

Comment: *it's easy when the value does not contain single quotes

Comment: Your heredoc is not a valid Ruby code.

Comment: @sawa ah, yeah, i got mixed with PHP, edited ^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be using HEREDOC for this, but here you go:

```
str = '\'`~!@#:;|$%^>?,)_+-={][&*(<]./"\''
```

Just use double quotes and escape the single quotes in the string. Simple.

Comment: Oh, I was wrong. I forgot Perl is a bit more "flexible" here with separators allowed :> Ruby limits to balanced forms like %q<..>.

Comment: yes, error `syntax error, unexpected end-of-input` after the symbol X

Comment: @SergioTulentsev, user: Nevermind. Just tried that. %q notation needs symbol delimiters.

Comment: @Kokizzu: Use my first option.

Answer (score 2):

Using heredoc:

```
bla = <<_
'`~!@#:;|$%^>?,)_+-={][&*(<]./"'
_
bla.chop!
```

you can observe the inspection and copy it:

```
"'`~!@#:;|$%^>?,)_+-={][&*(<]./\"'"
```

Simple as that.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use a heredoc to do this, and you can do this simply without using any escapes in your preparation.

```
>> %q '`~!@#:;|$%^>?,)_+-={][&*(<]./"' 
=> "'`~!@#:;|$%^>?,)_+-={][&*(<]./\"'"
```

The key here is that you are not using a *space* character in this collection of characters, and so we can use a *space* to delimit it.

You can use `%q` or `%Q` to do this.

Don't generally use space for delimiter for this, for obvious reasons, but sometimes it very useful.

Answer (score 0):

In that string you have every character that can be used to escape a string. So even `%q`/`%Q` won't help you to use this string verbatim.

```
%q('`~!@#:;|$%^>?,\)_+-={][&*\(<]./"')
# quoted parentheses
```

So, your only option is heredoc. With every other method, you'll have to backslash-escape some characters.